# What is the natural map $U_{A} \otimes_A \mathbb{Q}(q) \to U_q$ and what are the elements in $U_{\epsilon}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, quantum-groups

I am reading [the book](https://books.google.com.hk/books?id=bn5GNkLfnsAC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false). I am trying to understand the natural map $U_{A} \otimes_A \mathbb{Q}(q) \to U_q$ and the algebra $U_{\epsilon}$ on page 288 (Section 9.2).

[image]

[image]

What is the natural map $U_{A} \otimes_A \mathbb{Q}(q) \to U_q$ and what are the elements in $U_{\epsilon}$? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct the natural map, note that $U_q$ is a $\mathbb{Q}(q)$-module. Hence we can use this module structure to define
$$ X\otimes q\mapsto q\cdot X, \forall X\in U_{\mathcal{A}}.$$
This extends to the required map.
Note that the authors denote by $\mathbb{Q}(q)$ the field of rational functions in one variable over $\mathbb{Q}$, but by $\mathbb{Q}(\epsilon)$ the field obtained by adjoining a concrete complex number $\epsilon$ to $\mathbb{Q}$ within $\mathbb{C}$.